# Rails button_to delete credit card during spree checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm trying to enable the user to edit the number of credit cards they have on file, they'll have the option to delete it.

It would be simple enough in traditional rails, but I'm new to spree and not sure how things work during checkout.

In views:

```
  - @cards.each do |card|
    = card.last_digits
    = "#{card.month+'/'+card.year}"
    = button_to "delete", {:controller => :credit_cards,
          :action => 'destroy', :id => card.id, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'are you sure?'}
```

Controller:

```
module Spree
  class CreditCardsController < Spree::BaseController
    def destroy
      @credit_card = Spree::CreditCard.find(params["id"])
      @credit_card.destroy

.
.
.
```

Right now the button generated seems to work, when I press on it from checkout/payment it goes to checkout/update/payment and then stops at checkout/confirm but the credit card in not deleted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

what's the filename of your controller? are you intending to override the spree class CreditCardsController? if so:

```
Spree::CreditCardsController.class_eval do
  def destroy
    @credit_card = Spree::CreditCard.find(params["id"])
    @credit_card.destroy
    ...
  end
end
```

...but i think that controller method is in the Api namespace. what about calling the drop_payment_source method? https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/45cec5215763da26e0089415f4c49afffd683bd9/core/app/models/concerns/spree/user_payment_source.rb#L13

...if you want define your own `CreditCardsController` class then you should setup something in your routes.rb file so you can use a route helper method in the `button_to` method (instead of calling out the controller & method name). also, you need to redirect or something in your `destroy` method. maybe to `checkout_path`? run `rake routes` to find more.